# For application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) how to implement custom completionHandler?

Tags: swift, push-notification, closures, silent-notification

Hi I'm new to Swift programming. So I have the following function:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        ...some tasks...
        // want to call completionHandler here!
    }
```

This function runs when the phone receives a silent push notification. I was wondering if it was possible to run a custom completion handler upon `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method finishing?

If this is not possible, and `completionHandler` is some Swift specific function that is not up for change, what is its purpose? I've done some research and all I see is people simply calling `completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData)` towards the end of `didReceiveRemoteNotification`.

Thanks